# Can't get JavaScript to load in Eclipse web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am trying to load JavaScript from an external file in an Eclipse web application.

My folder structure is as follows:

nata
....src
........main
............webapp
................scripts
....................jquery.js
....................nata.js

I invoke the web app by: "localhost:8080/nata/login"

I have tried

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/nata/login/scripts/nata.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/nata/scripts/nata.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/scripts/nata.js"></script>
```

but all to no avail. The Javascript will not load.

```
Here is my html:  
<html>
<head>
<title>First Page</title>
<script src="scripts/nata.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Load Test</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph</p>
<button onclick="displayDate()" type="button">Display Date</button>
</body>
</html>

Here is nata.js:
function displayDate() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date(); }
```

When I put the HTML in a windows file (and use the following line)

```
<script src="nata.js"></script>
```

in folder X and put nata.js in the same folder X, the JavaScript works perfectly.

I have tried all of the lines below:

```
<script src="/scripts/nata.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/nata.js"></script>
<script src="nata/login/nata.js"></script>
<script src="/nata/login/nata.js"></script>
<script src="/nata/nata.js"></script>
<script src="nata/nata.js"></script>
```

and probably several more combinations.

I get the error message "displayDate() is undefined"

Sometimes I get the error message "Syntax error" on line 1 of nata.js. However, as I mentioned above, when I put the same HTML and the same nata.js side by side in a windows folder and open the HTML file with a browser and click the button, the JavaScript works perfectly. I just can't get it to load the JavaScript inside an Eclipse web app.

Comment: could you tell what is `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` ?

Comment: I got that expression from here: www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ResourceUrlProblems. Quoting from that article, I found "... To do so in JSP 2.0, we can use an EL expression as follows:

${pageContext.request.contextPath}" Using this expression in HTML allows one to dynamically grab the context path so that it doesn't matter to the HTML pages what the context path happens to be.

Comment: did you try relative path? <script src="scripts/nata.js"></script>